# Left Join Hangs

Tags: t-sql, left-join

I am trying to figure out what could be causing a left join to hang.  I've narrowed a problem down to a specific table but I can't for the life of me figure out what might be going on.  Basically, I have two tables, lets call them table A and table B.  When I left join table A to table B (its a 1 to 1 relationship with table B not always having a related record to table A) the query hangs.  When I inner join table A to table B, it runs in about a half second returning about 27,000 records.  Why is it when I run a left join, which should take a bit longer but not by much, it hangs?  Could I have bad data in table B?  The fields I'm joining are bigint's.  I'm stumped on this one.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my sql:

```
select
RegMemberTrip.idmember,
RegParent1.idMember_Parent1,
regparent1.idParent1
from
regmembertrip
left join
regparent1 on RegMemberTrip.idmember = regparent1.idMember_Parent1
where
regmembertrip.IDRound = 25
```

- RegParent1 is a view
- If I change the where criteria to '= 24' it works fine.  IDRound = 25 is fairly new data.  And like I said, if I keep this the way it is (idround = 25) with an inner join it works fine.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Could you provide some more info? What's the schema of each table? Some example data? There are too many unknowns to get a proper answer at the moment.

Comment: Without any sql, there is no point for this question to exist.

Comment: I edited my initial post with the sql and more of an explanation.  Hope this helps.  Thanks for your replies.

Comment: How many rows in total in Table A and how many in Table B?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the execution path tool in the Management Console? Are you sure your left join is not in fact doing a giant cartesian product across A and B?